# Python Get list of dictionaries from nested dictionary where value is greater than

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem. I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
{1: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 2: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 3: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 4: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 5: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 6: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 7: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 8: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 9: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, 10: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}}
```

What I need to do is craete an array/list with all the dictionaries with an `amount` greater than `10`. I already had the following:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x['amount'] >= 10, myDict.values()))
```

But this results in a list with only the values of the dictionaries, but I want them to contain the key as well.

I got this right now as result:

```
[{'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}, {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}]
```

But this is what I need:

```
[{1: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}}, {2: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}}, etc]
```

How can I include the keys as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, a list comprehension should work:

```
out = [{k:v} for k,v in my_data.items() if v['amount']>=10]
```

or using `filter`:

```
out = [*map(dict, zip(filter(lambda x: x[1]['amount']>=10, my_data.items())))]
```

Output:

```
[{1: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}},
 {2: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}},
 {3: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}},
 ...
 {9: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}},
 {10: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}}]
```

For a dictionary that you could traverse by key, it's even simpler:

```
out = {k:v for k,v in my_data.items() if v['amount']>=10}
```

or

```
out = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1]['amount']>=10, my_data.items()))
```

where the output:

```
{1: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0},
 2: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0},
 3: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0},
 ...
 9: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0},
 10: {'amount': 200.0, 'quantity': 0}}
```

Comment: And how do I iterate over that list, with a `key` and `value`, so something like this I mean: `for key, value in out`? I need to loop trough that list, and I need the key as well as the value

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk you’ll have to iterate over the list: `for d in out for k,v in d.items()`. But if your goal is something like that, then maybe a list is not a good data structure; maybe a dictionary is a better choice.